# Passing JSON Object to variable

Tags: json, variables, object

I'm trying to pass the last ID variables which is returning by openURL method. This is the code:

```
" + ": function() {
    formCount++;
    $( "#form tbody" ).append('<tr class="test"><td><input type="text" id="requirement'+formCount+'" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td><td><input type="text" id="objects'+formCount+'" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td><td><input type="text" id="andor'+formCount+'" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td><td><input type="text" id="qty'+formCount+'" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td><td><div id="del'+formCount+'"><img src="themes/balance/images/delete_button.png" style="cursor:pointer; margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom: 5px;" alt="Delete" /></div></td></tr>');
                    
    /* Delete requirement from database */
    $("#del"+formCount).click(function(param) {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove(); // removes whole row in layout
        var ReqID = ?????;
        var query = '.requirements.deleteRequirement/'+gameID+'/'+ReqID+''; 
        openURL(url+query, function(param) { });
        //alert(url+query);            
    });

    /* Add requirement to database */
    var query = '.requirements.createRequirement/'+gameID+'/Location/'+id+'/PLAYER_HAS_ITEM/1/1/1/1';
    openURL(url+query, function(param) { 
        var CaughtID = new Boolean(param.lastID);
        if(CaughtID.valueOf()) {
            $(".test").append('<input type="hidden" id="reqID'+formCount+'" value="'+param.lastID+'" />')
        }
        param.lastID = 0; // important! Prevent to keep the last value in the object after add (check in DOM ;) )
        
    });
}
```

My problem is that to pass param.lastID to **ReqID**. I tried `$("#reqID"+formCount).val()` but it returns undefined, probably because asynchronous function. My question is, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you assigning a function to `" + "`? I hope this is a type-o...

Comment: So, you're assigning a function to a button?? An anonymous one at that???

Answer (score 0):

The only parameter to an event handler is the event object.

If I understand your code correctly, you're trying to get the value you set when you created the object. You'll have to pull the data from the value:

`var ReqID = $(this).val()`

This will give you back a string, and it's up to you to make it work in your code.

EDIT:

Where is `"#del" + formCount` defined? You might need a different selector... maybe something like this:

`var ReqID = $('reqID' + formCount).val();`

Comment: "#del" + formCount is defined right here $( "#form tbody" ).append

Comment: And my solution didn't work? Specifically the second one I gave. That seems to be where you're storing that data. You should probably grab the data before you remove everything...

Comment: Shame, it's not working, I'm getting undefined value in var ReqID = $('reqID' + formCount).val(); and alert(url+query) returns this http://clip2net.com/s/165wq

Comment: On chrome or firebug in firefox you can inspect an individual element and look at the live data. Is the data there? Are you deleting the element before you try to access it?

Comment: in reqID + formCount is correct data but probably it appears there after var ReqID = $('reqID' + formCount).val(); is created, thats the problem I think...

Comment: What is this: `$(this).parent().parent().remove();` doing? Is that removing the data you're trying to access? I'm not sure what exactly is going on...

Comment: it removes whole $( "#form tbody" ).append

Comment: And all the stuff you added in $(".test").append